# Is the hypercube graph $Q_n$ k-factorable for k=modn?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Definition of k-factorable graph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_factorization

I have proved that a hypercube of any dimension has a perfect matching, thus also a 1-factorization.
Can it be proven that for any n, the graph $Q_n$ has a k-factorization if and only if k divides n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A $k$-factorization of a graph is a partition of the edge set of the graph into spanning $k$-regular subgraphs.  If the edge set of $Q_n$ is the disjoint union of some number of $k$-regular spanning subgraphs, then clearly $k$ divides the degree of a vertex (which is $n$).

To prove the converse, suppose $k$ divides $n$.  Because $Q_n$ is an $n$-regular bipartite graph, by a consequence of Hall's matching theorem, the edge set of $Q_n$ can be partitioned into $n$ perfect matchings.  (In other words, the edge-coloring number, also known as chromatic index, of $Q_n$ is exactly $n$.)  Thus, the edge set of $Q_n$ can be partitioned into $n$ perfect matchings (i.e. $n$ 1-factors). The union of any $k$ of the $n$ 1-factors gives a $k$-factor.  Thus, the $n$ 1-factors of $Q_n$ give a partition of the edge set of $Q_n$ into $n/k$ $k$-factors. Hence, $Q_n$ is $k$-factorizable if $k$ divides $n$.

Comment: Can you please expand a little on how k divides the degree of a vertex (or all vertices?)?

Comment: Suppose the edge set $E=E(Q_n)$ is the disjoint union of edge sets $E_1,E_2,\ldots,E_r$, where the subgraph $E_i$ is a $k$-regular spanning subgraph.  A vertex $u \in V(Q_n)$ has $n$ edges incident to it.  Of these $n$ edges, $k$ edges are in $E_1$, another $k$ edges are in $E_2$, and so on.  Hence, $n=kr$, which implies that $k$ divides $n$.